# Is it possible to like a Facebook page via an Android application without using web view?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-webview, facebook-like

Is it possible to like a Facebook page via an Android application without using web view?

I know it is an old question, but I still can't find the way to solve it. I want to like a Facebook page by just clicking a button in my Android application.

Page example: https://www.facebook.com/120676358039573

Many posts are telling me [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) can not like a page, and I don't want to use WebView because users may need to login again in the frame. (User have already logged in to my application with their Facebook account by SSO before).

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to send them to your page use `fb://page/[Page ID]`

hope this helps

Example `fb://page/454477637925610`